# MGTwitterEngine - efficient way to get and cache profile imags

Tags: iphone, caching, twitter

What is the most efficient way to get and cache a profile image for a user using MGTwitter?

Our problem currently is that there must be a call to `getUserInformationFor` to get the url of the image, then `getImageAtURL` resulting in two calls to the server. Currently, we just need the image information, so its redundant to have to download all the other information. When you bear in mind that we might do 20-30 of these calls at once (e.g. to get a list of user profile images), this become quite slow.

Secondly, what is the most efficient way to cache that image so that it doesn't have to be downloaded every time (we don't mind assuming that the profile image is never going to change), currently we're just writing to NSTemporaryDirectory() with the Twitter username as the filename, and then for each Twitter request checking if the filename exists in that directory. Is there a better, more efficient approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do something outside the bounds of the functionality available in MGTwitterEngine you'll probably have to use the raw Twitter API.  Try [this](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/profile_image/%3ascreen_name) page for some help.

Caching should probably be done in the `NSCachesDirectory` though.  It may have a longer lifetime than `NSTemporaryDirectory` and is the recommended place to store cached data.  Efficiency, in this case, probably means downloading once, storing the image so you can easily identify it later, determining if it exists and determining whether a download is needed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would write my own code using NSURLConnection (or ASIHTTPRequest) to download the profile image from the URL specified in the tweet NSDictionary.

Save the downloaded images in the Caches Directory. **The filename should be something like <username>.png** (all images from Twitter are generally png's) . This way finding images in the cache doesn't require NSDictionaries to store all of the image names.

I would also recommend adding a user controlled clearing of this cache, as it can grow to large sizes, and it can be potentially inaccurate if a user changes profile images.

Rebuilding the cache could be done when a cached image is two days old and the user is on WiFi.